# nginx 403 forbidden error + mac + laravel

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

Here is my nginx's content.

My current access url is http://localhost/lampi/, and I am receiving response `403 forbidden`.

My server's documentroot is /Library/WebServer/Documents/.

When I access http://localhost/, it shows ok. I can also see the index.html page's content.

I don't know what the matter is. I have checked top 10 pages in stackoverflow.

```
 server {

     server_name localhost;
     access_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx.host.access.log  main;

     root /Library/WebServer/Documents/;

     location / {
             #root html;
             index index.html index.htm index.php;
     }

     location /lampi {
             #autoindex on;
             if (!-e $request_filename){
                     rewrite  ^/lampi/(.*)$  /lampi/index.php?s=$1  last;
             }
     }

     location ~ \.php$ {
             include /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
             fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
             fastcgi_index index.php;
             fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /Library/WebServer/Documents/lampi/$fastcgi_script_name;
     }

     location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
             fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
             if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                     return 404;
             }

             fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
             fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

             fastcgi_index index.php;
             include fastcgi_params;
     }
     #location /images/ {
     #       root /usr/local/var/www;
     #}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three potential problems with your configuration file.

The use of `if (!-e $request_filename)` is causing problems because it checks for the existence of directories, and you should probably be using `try_files` anyway (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details):

```
location /lampi {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @lampi;
}
location @lampi {
    rewrite ^/lampi/(.*)$ /lampi/index.php?s=$1 last;
}
```

The value of `SCRIPT_FILENAME` adds an extra `/lampi` into the pathname. Use either of (both evaluate to the same value in this case):

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
```

For example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
}
```

The `location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$)` block is confusing. Normally it is adequate to use either `location ~ \.php$` or something like `location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$)` depending on whether or not your application uses PATH_INFO. Delete the block you are not using. See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) for details.